# In Coded UI, how to get a property and assert with it properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

In a Coded Ui Test, i want to validate a message in an application with the following code:

```
public void AssinarNewsletter()
    {
        //BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
        BrowserWindow chrome = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://pp.psafe.com/");
        chrome.Maximized = true;

        UITestControl uIEmail = new UITestControl(chrome);
        uIEmail.TechnologyName = "Web";
        uIEmail.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Edit");
        uIEmail.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "mce-EMAIL");
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIEmail, "andre.mendes@peseife.com.br");

        UITestControl uICadastrar = new UITestControl(chrome);
        uICadastrar.TechnologyName = "Web";
        uICadastrar.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Button");
        uICadastrar.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "mc-embedded-subscribe");
        Mouse.Click(uICadastrar);

        UITestControl uICadastrado = new UITestControl(chrome);
        uICadastrado.TechnologyName = "Web";
        uICadastrado.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Pane");
        uICadastrado.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "mce-success-response");

        string displayed = (string)uICadastrado.GetProperty("InnerText");
        string expected = "Quase no final... Precisaamos confirmar o seu endereço de e-mail. Para concluir o processo de assinatura, clique no link existente no e-mail que acabamos de enviar para você.";

        if (displayed != expected)
        {
            Assert.Fail("A mensagem está incorreta");
        }
```

But somehow, my test passed when it shouldn't.

Below is the message in the application:

[image: Newsletter-successful]

Comment: What's the value of `displayed` at the moment of the comparison? Also, are you sure the condition of failure is for `displayed` and `expected` to have the same value?

Comment: The value displayed is "Quase no final... Precisamos confirmar o seu endereço de e-mail. Para concluir o processo de assinatura, clique no link existente no e-mail que acabamos de enviar para você.". I have pretty much sure that they are NOT, that's why i wonder why the test has passed.

Comment: I think one of the two of us are confused... your condition is `if (displayed == expected)`; now you're saying that `displayed` and `expected` have **different** values. As they have different values, the condition is not met. Maybe what you were trying to do was `if (displayed != expected)`?

Comment: My intention is to make the test fail, then fix it to make it pass. This assert i took from an example found on google. Maybe i'm confused because i did not completly understand it.

Comment: @Josh Part You were right, i updated my post. But my test still passes.

Comment: Try using `Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, displayed, "A mensagem está incorreta" );`. This should do the same thing. Otherwise debug the test and copy the displayed text exactly to the expected string.

Answer (score 2):

Add a delay such as

```
UITestControl uICadastrado = new UITestControl(chrome);
uICadastrado.WaitForControlReady(1000);//wait one second
```

Put in a break point then run the test in debug by opening Test Explorer, Right Click on the Test Case and Click Run in Debug.

Change

```
if( displayed != expected )
```

To

```
if ( String.Equals(displayed , expected ) == false )
```

Or

```
if ( ! String.Equals(displayed , expected ) )
```